# What's the correct syntax for options when generating Blueprint CSS files in SSH with Ruby command?

Tags: css, ruby, ssh, blueprint-css

I need to generate default Blueprint CSS files using a Ruby command in the Shell. However the column_width, amount and gutter parameters aren't coming trough. I think i don't understand the syntax...

is this correct:

`ruby compress.rb -o /var/www/css/blueprint/src/ -p 70 15 12`

for this documentation?

```
joshua-claytons-computer:lib joshuaclayton$ ruby compress.rb -h
Usage: compress.rb [options]
Blueprint Compressor

options
  -o, --output_path=OUTPUT_PATH    Define a different path to output generated CSS files to.
  -n, --namespace=BP_NAMESPACE     Define a namespace prepended to all Blueprint classes (e.g. .your-ns-span-24)
  -p, --project=PROJECT_NAME       If using the settings.yml file, PROJECT_NAME is the project name you want to export
      --column_width=COLUMN_WIDTH  Set a new column width (in pixels) for the output grid
      --gutter_width=GUTTER_WIDTH  Set a new gutter width (in pixels) for the output grid
      --column_count=COLUMN_COUNT  Set a new column count for the output grid
  -h, --help                       Show this help message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the usage help I think you will need to specify the argument names instead of relying simply on their position. Also you specified the -p parameter without providing a project name. Perhaps something like this will work better for you:

```
ruby compress.rb -o /var/www/css/blueprint/src/ --column_width=70 --gutter_width=15 --gutter_width=12
```

Comment: It could be me, as a matter of fact it's pretty clear that it's me. But i find it very unclear that I -should- use the --column/--gutter options, but that I -shouldn't use the --output_path spec... Anyway your solution works, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... you did specify the --output_path albeit with the short name -o.